# Experiencing java.lang.StackOverflowError Exception ,When calling method

Tags: java, json, recursion

I have written a code which parses the JSON body in map it works fine but when JSONArray is detected it throws exception after some iterations.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class JsonToMapConv {

    private static HashMap<String, Object> mapReturn = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public static JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String json ="{\"menu\": {\n" +
"    \"header\": \"SVG Viewer\",\n" +
"    \"items\": [\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Open\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"OpenNew\", \"label\": \"Open New\"},\n" +
"     \n" +
"        {\"id\": \"ZoomIn\", \"label\": \"Zoom In\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"ZoomOut\", \"label\": \"Zoom Out\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"OriginalView\", \"label\": \"Original View\"},\n" +
"       \n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Quality\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Pause\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Mute\"},\n" +
"   \n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Find\", \"label\": \"Find...\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"FindAgain\", \"label\": \"Find Again\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Copy\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"CopyAgain\", \"label\": \"Copy Again\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"CopySVG\", \"label\": \"Copy SVG\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"ViewSVG\", \"label\": \"View SVG\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"ViewSource\", \"label\": \"View Source\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"SaveAs\", \"label\": \"Save As\"},\n" +
"        \n" +
"        {\"id\": \"Help\"},\n" +
"        {\"id\": \"About\", \"label\": \"About Adobe CVG Viewer...\"}\n" +
"    ]\n" +
"}}";

       HashMap<String, Object> map = createHashMapFromJsonString(json,"");        
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {            
          if(!entry.getValue().toString().contains("{"))  
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        }               
   }  

public static HashMap<String, Object> createHashMapFromJsonString(String json,String prefix) {

    System.out.println("prefix " + prefix);

    if(json.startsWith("[",0)){
        json = json.replace("[", "");
        json = json.replace("]", "");
        String subString = json.substring(2,7);       

        String[] parts = json.split("(?=\\{\""+subString+")");        

        for(int i=0; i< parts.length; i++ ){
            if(null != parts[i] && parts[i].length()>0){
                if(parts[i].charAt(parts[i].length() - 1)==','){                
                    System.out.println("parts[for]-"+ i+"   is "+parts[i] + "with prefix " + prefix );                
                    parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0,parts[i].length() - 1);  
                }
            createHashMapFromJsonString(parts[i], prefix+"_"+i); 
          }            
        }
    }    
    else{
        JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(json);   
        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = object.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = iterator.next(); 
            String key = entry.getKey();

            if(prefix.length()!=0){
                key = prefix + "."+key;
            }

            JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
            if (null != value) {            
                if (!value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                    if (value.isJsonObject()) {                        
                        mapReturn.put(key, createHashMapFromJsonString(value.toString(),key));
                    } else if (value.isJsonArray() && value.toString().contains(":")) {

                        List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        JsonArray array = value.getAsJsonArray();
                        if (null != array) {
                            for (JsonElement element : array) {
                                list.add(createHashMapFromJsonString(value.toString(),key));
                            }                 
                            mapReturn.put(key, list);
                        }
                    } else if (value.isJsonArray() && !value.toString().contains(":")) {                    
                        mapReturn.put(key, value.getAsJsonArray());
                    }              
                } else {
                    mapReturn.put(key, value.getAsString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mapReturn;
  }
}
```

The Exception i am experincing is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:547)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
```

The sample json, i have used is from https://json.org/example.html website .
In order to test the code just reassign the json string with required value.

Comment: Please share the FULL stacktrace of the exception.,

Comment: The whole stacktrace is missing...especially the line that refers to your code...

Comment: the stacktrace is same and in continues manner.at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
 at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:559)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Why don’t you use the json parser to parse the whole json string instead of mixing it up with your own parsing?

Comment: Try [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for JSON parsing rather than writing a parser of your own.

Comment: thanks Joakim for other approach ,my code works perfectly with other nested JSON but with array Json it's experiencing exception.

Comment: the stacktrace is not the same for sure! I can't see any reference to a line of your code which is always the case for a full stacktrace. how else should somebody know which line is causing the error?! The root of the stacktrace is missing, the line of your code

Comment: Hello AKSW, the stack trace is same as shared it is present in repetitive way.I am still stuck here

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown on `entry.getValue().toString()` for one of the map entries, since this entry's value contains the original map.
To see which entry it is, simple debug your application, and look at the value of `map` after calling `createHashMapFromJsonString(json,"")`.

[image]

---

**That said, I strongly suggest that you use an existing JSON parsing framework**, as advised in the comments to your question.
There is no point in "inventing the wheel".
A library which is **widely used**, for a **long period of time**, by **many users**, is much less likely to have bugs than any newly written code.

Comment: I have some hands on GSON .Inorder to fetch back the parsed data you need to use a mapping Class or you should have knowledge of elements arranged in JSON both approach are not use full for me as  I am writing a generic code and i am half way through it.

Comment: You could use Jackson without having a mapping class, using `JsonNode` and its subclasses. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_tree_model.htm

Comment: Same thing exists in GSON, using `JsonObject`